# HATEOAS methods not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

My controller can't seem to find the HATEOAS methods like `linkTo`. Am I missing something?

#### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>provider</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <!-- Auto configured, remove dependencies to disable. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- OAuth 2.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MongoDB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring REST MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Dozer: DTO/Entity Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.provider.core.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

#### AccountController.java

```java
package com.provider.core;

import org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper;
import org.dozer.Mapper;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.provider.account.Account;
import com.provider.account.AccountDTO;

@Controller
public class AccountController
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountController.class);
    @Autowired private AccountRepository repo;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "account", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<AccountDTO> createAccount(
        @RequestBody AccountDTO accountDto)
    {
        logger.info("Start createAccount()");
        Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
        Account account = mapper.map(accountDto, Account.class);
        Account savedAccount = repo.save(account);
        AccountDTO savedAccountDto = mapper.map(savedAccount, AccountDTO.class);
        
        // DOES NOT COMPILE "linkto" not defined.
        savedAccountDto.add(linkTo(AccountController.class)
                       .slash(savedAccountDto.getId()).withSelfRel());
        
        return new ResponseEntity<AccountDTO>(savedAccountDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by adding `org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.15.0.RELEASE` to your pom.xml, and then `import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.*`.

Comment: That worked. Would have sworn I had the HATEOAS dependency in my pom. Why not drop that in as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like your POM is missing the `spring-hateoas` dependency.

So first add this to pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>0.15.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can add this static import and your code should compile:

```java
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.*
```

Comment: superEb was right!
FYI - in gradle it's:
dependencies {
compile 'org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas'
}

Comment: **Hateos1.0.m1** has quite a number of changes, refer to this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/05/spring-hateoas-1-0-m1-released)

Comment: and what about import org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule; class? what is new changed name for this?

Comment: If you don't know which version is compatible with your spring boot version, just don't add the version number (gradle example: implementation 'org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas'). Spring will pick the right one itself.

Answer (score 117):

In case you are using HATEOAS v1.0 and above (Spring boot >= 2.2.0), do note that the classnames have changed. Notably the below classes have been renamed:

- `ResourceSupport` changed to `RepresentationModel`
- `Resource` changed to `EntityModel`
- `Resources` changed to `CollectionModel`
- `PagedResources` changed to `PagedModel`
- `ResourceAssembler` changed to `RepresentationModelAssembler`

More information available in the official documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/).

When using Spring boot starter, the below dependency would suffice to include HATEOAS:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Hoping this information will help someone like me who searched for hours to find why `Resource` class was not getting resolved.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was going insane. Every single tutorial mentioned Resource as an import, but I could never find the class on my classpath. It appears, then, that all the tutorials are outdated as of december 2019.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/ was recently upgraded to use this version.

Comment: and what is new alternative name for import org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule; class?

Comment: What happened to `ResourceProcessor`?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using HATEOAS in eclipse(Version : Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)), please note that the class names have changed.

```
Resource changed to EntityModel
Resources changed to CollectionModel
```

More information available in the official documentation below link ->

https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/

When using Spring boot starter, you've to use below dependency to include HATEOAS:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Demo Code :

```
EntityModel<Users> resource = new EntityModel<Users>(user);
        ControllerLinkBuilder linkTo = linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).retrieveAllUsers());
        resource.add(linkTo.withRel("all-users"));
```

Note : You have to import

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.*;
```

Hope this information is helpful to find why `Resource` class was not getting resolved !!

Answer (score 6):

```
    Add following dependency :-

    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
     <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    Follow Sample Code :-
    import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.*;
   
    @GetMapping(path = "/users/{id}")
    public EntityModel<User> getUserInfo(@PathVariable int id) {
        User user = userDao.getUser(id);
        
        EntityModel<User> entityModel = EntityModel.of(user);
        Link link = WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).getUserList()).withRel("user-list");
        entityModel.add(link);
        
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User not found with id : "+id);
        }
        return entityModel;
    }
```

Comment: Use your code to add Hateos. Before i used the:
` 
EntityModel.of(car,
                linkTo(methodOn(CarController.class).get(car.getId())).withSelfRel(),
                linkTo(methodOn(CarController.class).list()).withRel("cars"));
`
 method but it didn't work.

Comment: May I now the version of spring boot, you are using and what exactly the error, you are facing.

Comment: Version:
<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId><version>2.7.2</version></dependency>

Cannot resolve method 'of' in 'EntityModel' in:
`
@Component
public class CarResourceAssembler implements RepresentationModelAssembler<Car, EntityModel<Car>> {

    @Override
    public EntityModel<Car> toModel(Car car) {
        return EntityModel.of(car,
                linkTo(methodOn(CarController.class).get(car.getId())).withSelfRel(),
                linkTo(methodOn(CarController.class).list()).withRel("cars"));
}}

Comment: Please check following with spring boot version 2.7.2 and java 11 public class Greeting extends RepresentationModel<Greeting>{
 
 private final String content;

 @JsonCreator
 public Greeting(@JsonProperty("content") String content) {
  this.content = content;
 }

 public String getContent() {
  return content;
 }
}

Comment: @RestController
public class GreetingController {

 private static final String TEMPLATE = "Hello, %s!";

 @RequestMapping("/greeting")
 public HttpEntity<Greeting> greeting(
  @RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {

  Greeting greeting = new Greeting(String.format(TEMPLATE, name));
  greeting.add(linkTo(methodOn(GreetingController.class).greeting(name)).withSelfRel());

  return new ResponseEntity<>(greeting, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
}

Comment: @KevinOnofre plz check above two class, it is working fine.

Comment: I check now and let you know.

Answer (score 5):

Add below dependency in pom.xml,it could resolve your issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If above doesn't work then easy solution is got with older versions of hateos.

As new versions of Hateoas has been changed totally, below link can help you.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/

Am mentioning some major changes in methods of Hateoas

```
ResourceSupport is now RepresentationModel

Resource is now EntityModel

Resources is now CollectionModel

PagedResources is now PagedModel
```

The LinkDiscoverer API has been moved to the client package.

The LinkBuilder and EntityLinks APIs have been moved to the server package.

ControllerLinkBuilder has been moved into server.mvc and deprecated to be replaced by WebMvcLinkBuilder.

RelProvider has been renamed to LinkRelationProvider and returns LinkRelation instances instead of Strings.

VndError has been moved to the mediatype.vnderror package

Answer (score 2):

There are some nomenclature changes in the recent release(2.2.0 or >). Refer to [this document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna leave this here in case someone new needed it:
`ControllerLinkBuilder` is deprecated and you should use `WebMvcLinkBuilder` instead (check this https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/springframework/hateoas/server/mvc/ControllerLinkBuilder.html)

so instead if:

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.*;
```

use this:

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurred in my case because there are two hateoas jars one has the resource interface and other has the implementaion with same groupId and arifactId.
To Resolve this issue -->
Downgrade your STS if you're using 4.* to 3.*
Add the below dependency if you're using spring boot

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

After adding this dependency run below commands in the command prompt where you're pom.xml is present

1. mvn clean install package
2. mvn eclipse:eclipse

This steps resolved issue for me.

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 1):

Might be helpful for some, I see one thing thats not addressed here and couple of comments ask for this:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'hal'
Cannot resolve symbol 'Jackson2HalModule'
```

hal module is under media now. So

```
org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule
```

is now replaced with

```
org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.Jackson2HalModule
```

Answer (score 0):

The below imports are required

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Link;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder;
```

With a static import from `WebMvcLinkBuilder` for all methods

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, hateoas had a lot of changes. I still was running into the same issues though even with the names properly changed to EntityModel etc. because it wasn't letting me import anything from org.springframework.hateoas.

I was using maven with IntelliJ IDEA and had to right-click my pom.xml, -> maven, -> reload project. Then it let me import things from hateoas properly.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.*;
```