# Migrate Spring hateos ResourceAssembler to RepresentationModelAssembler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352764/hateoas-methods-not-found) `ResourceAssembler` is changed to `RepresentationModelAssembler`

I have this code which is using Spring HATEOAS 1.0:

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceAssembler;

public class BaseAssembler<T extends BaseTransaction, D extends BaseResource>
        implements ResourceAssembler<T, D> {
        ...
}
```

After migration to `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:2.6.4'`
I changed it to:

```
public class BaseAssembler<T extends BaseTransaction, D extends BaseResource>
        implements RepresentationModelAssembler<T, D> {
        .........
}
```

But I get error:

```
Type parameter 'D' is not within its bound; should extend 'org.springframework.hateoas.RepresentationModel<?>'
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is reporting that the type parameter `D` is not within its bound in your definition:

```java
public class BaseAssembler<T extends BaseTransaction, D extends BaseResource>
        implements RepresentationModelAssembler<T, D> {
        .........
}
```

In other words, it means that you cannot use `D extends BaseResource` to implement `RepresentationModelAssembler<T, D>` (note the type parameter `D` here) because that type *should extend 'org.springframework.hateoas.RepresentationModel<?>'*.

[`RepresentationModelAssembler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.2.11/api/org/springframework/hateoas/server/RepresentationModelAssembler.html) gives you the ability to convert between domain types, your entities, to [`RepresentationModel`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.2.11/api/org/springframework/hateoas/RepresentationModel.html)s, a based class conceived to enrich your DTOs to collect links.

It is defined as follows:

```java
public interface RepresentationModelAssembler<T, D extends RepresentationModel<?>>
```

Note again the definition of the type parameter `D`.

In your code you need to use something like:

```java
public class BaseAssembler<T extends BaseTransaction, D extends RepresentationModel<?>>
        implements RepresentationModelAssembler<T, D> {
        .........
}
```

Please, consider read for instance some [this](https://grapeup.com/blog/how-to-build-hypermedia-api-with-spring-hateoas/) or [this other](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/hateoas/spring-hateoas-tutorial/) article, they provide a great variety of examples and uses cases about showcasing how you can implement the desired behavior.

For example, given the following entity, extracted from one of the cited articles:

```java
@Entity
public class Director {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Getter
   private Long id;
   @Getter
   private String firstname;
   @Getter
   private String lastname;
   @Getter
   private int year;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "director")
   private Set<Movie> movies;
}
```

And the following DTO:

```java
@Builder
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Relation(itemRelation = "director", collectionRelation = "directors")
public class DirectorRepresentation extends RepresentationModel<DirectorRepresentation> {
   private final String id;
   private final String firstname;
   private final String lastname;
   private final int year;
}
```

Your `RepresentationModelAssembler` will look like:

```java
@Component
public class DirectorRepresentationAssembler implements RepresentationModelAssembler<Director, DirectorRepresentation> {
    @Override
    public DirectorRepresentation toModel(Director entity) {
        DirectorRepresentation directorRepresentation = DirectorRepresentation.builder()
                .id(entity.getId())
                .firstname(entity.getFirstname())
                .lastname(entity.getLastname())
                .year(entity.getYear())
                .build();
 
        directorRepresentation.add(linkTo(methodOn(DirectorController.class).getDirectorById(directorRepresentation.getId())).withSelfRel());
        directorRepresentation.add(linkTo(methodOn(DirectorController.class).getDirectorMovies(directorRepresentation.getId())).withRel("directorMovies"));
 
        return directorRepresentation;
    }
 
    @Override
    public CollectionModel<DirectorRepresentation> toCollectionModel(Iterable<? extends Director> entities) {
        CollectionModel<DirectorRepresentation> directorRepresentations = RepresentationModelAssembler.super.toCollectionModel(entities);
 
        directorRepresentations.add(linkTo(methodOn(DirectorController.class).getAllDirectors()).withSelfRel());
 
        return directorRepresentations;
    }
}
```

In terms of your interfaces and object model:

```java
@Entity
public class Director extends BaseTransaction{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Getter
   private Long id;
   @Getter
   private String firstname;
   @Getter
   private String lastname;
   @Getter
   private int year;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "director")
   private Set<Movie> movies;
}
```

```java
public class DirectorRepresentationAssembler
  extends BaseAssembler<Director, DirectorRepresentation>
  implements RepresentationModelAssembler<Director, DirectorRepresentation> {
  //... the above code
}
```

`DirectorRepresentation` is the same as presented above.

The [Spring HATEOAS reference guide itself](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#migrate-to-1.0) provides some guidance as well about the changes performed in Spring HATEOAS 1.0 and about how to migrate from the previous version. It even includes a [script](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/tree/main/etc) that may be of help.

In any case, as indicated above, in your use case you only need to modify the `BaseAssembler` interface to be defined in terms of the type `D extends RepresentationModel<?>`; then try relating in some way `BaseResource` to `RepresentationModel` or get rid of `BaseResource`s and use `RepresentationModel`s instead.

For example, you couild try defining `BaseResource` as follows:

```java
public class BaseResource extends RepresentationModel<BaseResource>{
  // your implementation
}
```

Then, the bound will be right:

```java
public class BaseAssembler<T extends BaseTransaction, D extends BaseResource>
    implements RepresentationModelAssembler<T, D> {
  // your implementation
}
```

With these changes, `DirectorRepresentation` will extend `BaseResource`:

```java
public class DirectorRepresentation extends BaseResource {

}
```

And you can extend `BaseAssembler` like this:

```java
public class DirectorRepresentationAssembler
    extends BaseAssembler<Director, DirectorRepresentation>
    implements RepresentationModelAssembler<Director, DirectorRepresentation> {
  // your implementation
}
```

In my opinion, the code you published in your repository is mostly fine. I think the only problem is in [this line of code](https://github.com/rcbandit111/hateos_poc/blob/5def44d3689d73e89f4874c92beed354f49ab528/src/main/java/com/hateos/test/entity/web/rest/resource/BaseResource.java#L10), as I mentioned before, I think you need to provide the type parameter when defining your `BaseResource` class. For instance:

```java
package com.hateos.test.entity.web.rest.resource;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.hateoas.RepresentationModel;

import java.util.UUID;

public class BaseResource extends RepresentationModel<BaseResource> {

  @JsonProperty
  @ApiModelProperty(position = 1, required = true)
  public UUID id;

  @JsonProperty
  public DateTime creationTime;

  @JsonProperty
  public DateTime lastUpdatedTime;

}
```

Please, note the inclusion of the code fragment `RepresentationModel<BaseResource>` after the `extends` keyword.

I am not sure if it will work but at least with this change every compiles fine and it seems to work properly.

Comment: I tested the code but still I get error. I pushed the code sample here: https://github.com/rcbandit111/hateos_poc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/hateos/test/entity/web/rest/payload/BaseAssembler.java Can you give me some advise what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @PeterPenzov. Sorry for the late reply, I just realized your comment. Thank you for testing the answer. I think your code is mostly fine. The problem could be in [this line of code](https://github.com/rcbandit111/hateos_poc/blob/5def44d3689d73e89f4874c92beed354f49ab528/src/main/java/com/hateos/test/entity/web/rest/resource/BaseResource.java#L10). As suggested in the answer, have you tried to parameterize `RepresentationModel`? I mean, use: `public class BaseResource extends RepresentationModel<BaseResource>`. Please, note the `RepresentationModel<BaseResource>` part. Please, could you try?

Comment: I tested the change and I think it works fine: at least the application compiles successfully.

Comment: Can you paste a code snippet for example here, please: https://pastebin.com/ or place it into your answer?

Comment: Of course @PeterPenzov. Please, see the updated answer. Please, could you try? I hope it helps.

Comment: ok, I can compile it. Thanks!

Comment: That is great @PeterPenzov!! I am very happy to hear it!!

Comment: I hope it's going to work properly when API requests are made.

Comment: I hope so. Please, do not hesitate to contact me again if necessary.